# Pyspark DataFrame count occurrences of value of a column in an other column

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I got a Dataframe that consists of:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+
|                 src|                 dst|linkage_count|
+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+
|             abc.com|        _spf.a22.biz|            0|
|             abc.com|     _spf.google.com|            0|
|     _spf.google.com|        _spf.mail.ru|            0|
+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+
```

Now I would like to loop through each row and take the value of the 'dst' column and find the amount of occurances of that 'dst' value in the 'src' column and add that to the 'linkage_count' column. So in this case the result should be:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+
|                 src|                 dst|linkage_count|
+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+
|             abc.com|        _spf.a22.biz|            0|
|             abc.com|     _spf.google.com|            1|
|     _spf.google.com|        _spf.mail.ru|            0|
+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+
```

Comment: shouldn't the last row of linkage_count be equal to 1, as _spf occurs in both dst and src for that row? or is _spf not important for the count?

Answer (score 0):

One way using a self join :

```
df.alias("l").join(df.alias("r"), col("l.dst") == col("r.src"), "left")\
             .groupBy("l.src", "l.dst")\
             .agg((count("r.src") + first("l.linkage_count")).alias("linkage_count"))\
             .show()
```

We use left join on `dst == src` and count number of matching which is added to `linkage_count` column.

Gives:

```
+---------------+---------------+-------------+
|            src|            dst|linkage_count|
+---------------+---------------+-------------+
|        abc.com|   _spf.a22.biz|            0|
|_spf.google.com|   _spf.mail.ru|            0|
|        abc.com|_spf.google.com|            1|
+---------------+---------------+-------------+
```